Jolt Mapping handling null and empty strings
I have the following input JSON value :
{
  "A": {
    "B": [
      {
        "tempName": "rq3ewas",
        "name": "test1"
      },
      {
        "tempName": "",
        "name": "test2"
      },
      {
        "tempName": null,
        "name": "test3"
      },
      {
        "tempName": "test4"
      }
    ]
  }
}

and want to get the following output based on ;
scenario1: If "tempname" is not null, then set the value of "name" to "tempName".
scenario2: If "tempname" is null, then keep the default value of "name" without changing it.
scenario3: If "tempname" is empty string(""), then keep the default value of "name" without changing it
scenario4: But If "tempname" is not present, then keep the default value of "name"
Except first scenario, last three are not working. If the code is modified last three works and first scenario is getting failed.
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "A": {
        "B": {
          "*": {
            "name": "=firstNotNull(@(1,tempName), @(2,name))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "A": {
        "B": {
          "*": {
            "tempName": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

O/p:
{
  "A" : {
    "B" : [ {
      "name" : "rq3ewas"
    }, {
      "name" : null
    }, {
      "name" : ""
    }, {
      "name" : "test4"
    } ]
  }
}

Expected O/p:
{
  "A" : {
    "B" : [ {
      "name" : "rq3ewas"
    }, {
      "name" : "test2"
    }, {
      "name" : "test3"
    }, {
      "name" : "test4"
    } ]
  }
}

[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "A": {
        "B": {
          "*": {
            "name": "=firstNotNull(@(1,tempName), @(2,name))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "A": {
        "B": {
          "*": {
            "tempName": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Here is the Input -
{
"A": {
"B": [
{
"tempName": "rq3ewas",
"name": "test1"
},
{
"tempName": "",
"name": "test2"
},
{
"tempName": null,
"name": "test3"
},
{
"tempName": "test4"
}
]
}
}

Below code is working and giving the expected output.
[ {
  "bI" : {
    "id" : "t1",
    "locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
    "tempName" : null,
    "name" : "Test1",
    "isActive" : false,
    "pT" : "Re"
  },
  "id" : "t1",
  "ContextID" : "id_ID",
  "cf" : {
    "name" : "asd"
  },
  "dE" : {
    "sS" : "arte"
  },
  "mk" : { },
  "pd" : { }
} ]


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Are you aware that this one is nothing but the expected output ?

Principally you should get rid of the empty string, since manipulating null valued attributes is possible with modify specs. Having aimed this, the following transformation might be used :
[
  { //concert "" valued "tempName" attribute's value to null,
    //while removing the null valued ones(doesn't matter)
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "tempName": {
              "": "&4.&3[&2].&1", //convert "" valued "tempName" attribute to to the one with null value
              "*": {
                "@1": "&5.&4[&3].&2"
              }
            },
            "*": "&3.&2[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //set "name" attributes by the values of the 
    //"tempName" attributes provided that they're non-null  
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "name": "=notNull(@(1,tempName))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //keep the "name" attributes only
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "tempName": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Hi, just FYI using JSLT this can be solved in few lines:
let array = [for(.A.B) {"name": if(.tempName) .tempName else .name  }]
{"A":{"B":$array } }

Thank you, This is working. Facing issue with one more spec similar for converting JSON to Array.
Input JSON:
[
  {
    "bI": {
      "id": "t1",
      "locale": [
        "id_ID",
        "id_ID"
      ],
      "tempName": "",
      "name": "Test1",
      "isActive": false,
      "pT": "Re"
    },
    "id": "t1",
    "ContextID": "id_ID",
    "cf": {
      "name": "asd"
    },
    "dE": {
      "sS": "arte"
    },
    "mk": {},
    "pd": {}
  }
]

spec applied:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "bI": {
          "*": "bI.&",
          "tempName": {
            "": "&2.&1",
            "*": {
              "@1": "&3.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

O/p:
{
  "bI" : {
    "id" : "t1",
    "locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
    "tempName" : null,
    "name" : "Test1",
    "isActive" : false,
    "pT" : "Re"
  },
  "id" : "t1",
  "ContextID" : "id_ID",
  "cf" : {
    "name" : "asd"
  },
  "dE" : {
    "sS" : "arte"
  },
  "mk" : { },
  "pd" : { }
}

Expected output:
[
{
  "bI" : {
    "id" : "t1",
    "locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
    "tempName" : null,
    "name" : "Test1",
    "isActive" : false,
    "pT" : "Re"
  },
  "id" : "t1",
  "ContextID" : "id_ID",
  "cf" : {
    "name" : "asd"
  },
  "dE" : {
    "sS" : "arte"
  },
  "mk" : { },
  "pd" : { }
}
]


Below code is working and giving the expected output.
[ {
"bI" : {
"id" : "t1",
"locale" : [ "id_ID", "id_ID" ],
"tempName" : null,
"name" : "Test1",
"isActive" : false,
"pT" : "Re"
},
"id" : "t1",
"ContextID" : "id_ID",
"cf" : {
"name" : "asd"
},
"dE" : {
"sS" : "arte"
},
"mk" : { },
"pd" : { }
} ]
